# Specific value subset replacement between two tables in r

Tags: r, replace, subset

I want to replace a certain value in column b, table 1 with the value in column b, table 2 **IF** the value in column a, table 1 equals the value in column a, table 2.

I tried this but it gives me an error about a replacement length issue

```
table1$b[is.na(match(table1$a, 
table2$a))] <- 
as.character(table2$b[match(table1$a, 
table2$a)])
```

This is a sample of the data I'm working on:

```
table1 <- data.frame (a = 
c("OP2775iia","OP2775iib","OP2958i_a","OP2958i_b","OP2958iia"),
                   b = c(COM,NA,NA,NA,COM))


table2 <- data.frame (a = c("OP2775iib","OP2958i_b"),
                      b = c(SAV,PAV))
```

I want an output where table1 entries 'OP2775iib' and 'OP2958i_b' have their respective column b values changed to 'SAV' and 'PAV' respectively.

Comment: Something like `table1$b[table1$a == table2$a] <- table2$b[table1$a == tabel2$a]` should do , or am I missing another requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `merge`:

```
table1 <- data.frame (a = c("OP2775iia","OP2775iib","OP2958i_a","OP2958i_b","OP2958iia"),
  b = c("COM",NA,NA,NA,"COM"), stringsAsFactors = F)

table2 <- data.frame (a = c("OP2775iib","OP2958i_b"),
  b = c("SAV","PAV"), stringsAsFactors = F)

names(table2) <- c("a", "b2")


(table3 <- merge(x = table1, y = table2, all.x = TRUE))
table3$bnew <- with(table3, ifelse(!is.na(b2), b2, b))
table3

#           a    b   b2 bnew
# 1 OP2775iia  COM <NA>  COM
# 2 OP2775iib <NA>  SAV  SAV
# 3 OP2958i_a <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 4 OP2958i_b <NA>  PAV  PAV
# 5 OP2958iia  COM <NA>  COM
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly... I have a follow up question I hope you can help me with. This code is in a while loop, and I have another procedure in that while loop which finds a value (name) for the last remaining NA at row 3. However, as the loop runs, the 'bnew' column is overwritten and I lose the values that we just included here.. so essentially I need to store the values in a single table as the while loop iterates. I tried using the 'append' function but cant seem to get the syntax right. Could you please help?